# Rails - paperclip - multiple image creation no-method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I have been trying to create a sample apple but I've been stuck on this one part for **WEEKS !** I have been spamming stackoverflow but I've had no luck :(.
I'm trying to create a products page that also allows for multiple image upload. So I have a user model a product model and a photo model. When i submit the form filled with photos and other inputs I get this error.

```
NoMethodError in ProductsController#create

undefined method `photo' for #<Product:0x9078f74>
```

**new product page**

```
= form_for @product, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
  %p
    = f.label :description
    = f.text_field :description

  = fields_for @photo, :html => {:multipart => true} do |fp|
    = fp.file_field :image 

  %p.button
    = f.submit
```

**products controller**

```
  def new
    @product = Product.new
    @photo   = Photo.new
  end

  def create
    @photo = current_user.photos.build(params[:photo])  
    @product = current_user.products.build(params[:product])
  end
```

**product model**

```
attr_accessible :description, :name, :photo, :image

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos

  validates :user_id,      presence: true
  validates :description,  presence: true
  validates :photo,        presence: true
end
```

**photo model**

```
  attr_accessible :image
  belongs_to :product
  validates_attachment :image, presence: true
```

**user model**

```
attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :image, :photo

  has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :photos, :through => :products

end
```

**tables**

User

- id
- name
- email
- password

product

- id
- name
- description
- user id

photo

- id
- image_file_name
- image_content_type
- image_file_size
- image_updated_at
- product_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your products model

has_many :photos
  
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
  
attr_accessible :description, :name, :photos_attributes

Answer (score 4):

Change the **Products controller** to

```
def new
  @product = Product.new
  @product.photos.build
end

def create  
  @product = Product.new(params[:product])
end
```

Since you have asked for multiple image upload try adding this to your view

```
   <%= f.fields_for :photos do |img| %>
        <%= render "img_fields", :f => img %>
   <% end %>
   <div class="add_image"><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Image", f, :photos %></div>
```

and create a file _img_fields.html.erb to the views and add

```
<div class="entry_field">
    <label>Image :</label>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
    <%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %></div>
```

Then add the following lines to your application.js file

```
function remove_fields(link) {
        $(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");
        $(link).closest(".entry_field").hide();
}

function add_fields(link, association, content) {
        var new_id = new Date().getTime();
        var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g");
        $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
}
```

In your products model

```
  has_many :photos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :photos_attributes
```

Comment: after i change the products controller that gives me NoMethodError in Products#new  undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class Extracted source (around line #18): 18:   = fields_for @photo, :html => {:multipart => true} do |fp|

Comment: I think you have not changed the view file as specified. Change the views as <%= f.fields_for :photos do |img| %><%= img.file_field :image %><% end %> if you want to add only one image or if you want to upload multiple image then follow as per told in the answer.

Comment: undefined method `link_to_remove_fields' for #<#<Class:0xb5a84f0c>:0xa091b2c>

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
= fields_for @photo, :html => {:multipart => true} do |fp|
```

To:

```
= fields_for :photos, :html => {:multipart => true} do |fp|
```

And in your controller:

```
  def new
    @product = Product.new
    @product.photos.build
  end
```

And in your Product model:

```
attr_accessible :description, :name, :photos_attributes
```

Comment: Hmnn i did that but it get an interesting error. Routing Error no route matched [post] But in my config/routes.rb i have resources :products and resources:photos so...  Google said it had something to do with the :product in the form